# Bootstrap 3 columns same order for both LTR and RTL

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 3 columns that I want to be in the same order for both left to right LTR and right to left RTL.

I use this https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl for RTL support for bootstarp.

Here is the LTR code:

[www.bootply.com/14fHNNoMnQ](http://www.bootply.com/14fHNNoMnQ)

and here is the RTL code:

[www.bootply.com/WmAp0cjzET](http://www.bootply.com/WmAp0cjzET)

I need the three columns stacked on xs and sm devices:

```
A
B
C
```

and on md and lg devices for both LTR and RTL ordered as:

```
B | A | C
```

I do not mind using tables also.

Answer (score 1):

check this out its exactly what you where looking for:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap

Bootstrap provides a great way to handle this scenario, the push and pull column classes. The push class will move columns to the right while the pull class will move columns to the left.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4 col-md-4 col-md-push-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-pull-4 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div>B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div>C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this will give you what you asked for:

three columns stacked on xs and sm devices:

```
A
B
C
```

and on md and lg devices for both LTR and RTL ordered as:

```
B | A | C
```

Answer (score -1):

Plaese check this approach.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
      Left column
    </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
    <b>
    Center column<br>
    Center column<br>
    Center column<br>
    </b>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
    Right column
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Pramodini Priyadarsini